# How to re-use the coefficient matrix decomposition result when solving linear systems by Eigen C++

Tags: linear-solver, c++, efficiency, eigen

My problem needs to solve dense symmetric linear systems something like:

`A x = b`,
`A y = x`,
`A z = y+x`,...in sequence.

In Eigen C++, if I take advantage of the symmetry of `A` by using:

```
x=A.ldlt().solve(b);
y=A.ldlt().solve(x);
z=A.ldlt().solve(y+x);
```

The same matrix `A` has to be `Cholesky` factorized many times.

Similar issue may exists for `householderQR` and `LU` algorithms.

How can I reuse the coefficient matrix decomposition result for other systems?

It seems this is equivalent to ask whether there is a simple back-substitution solver for upper triangular linear systems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to declare a LDLT object like this:

```
LDLT<MatrixXd> ldlt(A);
x = ldlt.solve(b);
y = ldlt.solve(x);
...
```

Comment: Thank you. So if I have `A` changed in a loop, then just re-declare it?

Comment: There is a compute method like this: `ldlt.compute(B);`

Answer (score 2):

Given that the accepted answer has typos and does not give full code, I decided to post mine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
int main()
{
    MatrixXd A;
    A.resize(3,3);
    VectorXd b;
    b.resize(3);

    A <<
      13, 5, 7 ,
      5 , 9, 3 ,
      7 , 3, 11;
    b << 3, 3, 4;

    cout << "Here is the matrix A:\n" << A << endl;
    cout << "Here is the vector b:\n" << b << endl;
    LDLT<MatrixXd> L = A.ldlt();
    VectorXd x = L.solve(b);
    cout << "The solution is:\n" << x << endl;
    cout << "reconstructed b is:\n"  << A*x << endl; 

}
```